# Form of a joint distribution table of random vectors and missing vectors

Tags: joint-distribution, vector

I am trying to follow this lecture on [variational autoencoders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzEywGCT7-A). When talking about random observed data $o$ with missing components $m$ (min 14:10) he states that to calculate the log-likelihood of your data $X$ you need to marginalize out the missing components  $P(X) = P(o,m)$. However, I can't quite visualize how you can build a joint pdf with vectors that are not constant in size?

For example, let's say the probability of an observed vetor $o_1 = (1, 2, -)$ with missing component $m_3 = 3$ is 0.3. How would the entry of the joint pdf table $P(o,m)$ would look like? Is this correct? I think Im just getting stupidly confuse with the unimportant fact whether if the data is 1 or N-dimensional

|  | $o_1$ | $o_2$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $m_1$ |  |  |
| $m_2$ |  |  |
| $m_3$ | 0.3 |  |